# Time Machine: Mobile incremental Backup

Tags: time-machine, hard-drive, backup, external-disk

Imagine I do backups using Time Machine at home just like everybody else. But as I travel often and of course also work on the road I also need to have a mobile backup solution. I thought about the following:

One partition of my external hard drive has the same size like my internal hard drive (e.g. 500GB). I use Carbon Copy Cloner to clone my internal hard drive daily. The second partition of my external hard drive backups all changes starting from last cloning on; only if manually activated when I leave home for a longer time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In Mountain Lion and greater, you can create [multiple separate backup disks](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11452?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) with Time Machine. Get an USB external HD for traveling, and use that to backup your Mac whilst on the road. When at home, you can do a backup to another HD, (USB or otherwise,) which stays there permanently. I take [this external HD](http://www.lacie.com/us/products/product.htm?id=10599) when I travel. It is wicked fast, and demonstrably rugged, as I have dropped it several times with no ill effects. You can also use this disk to make a CCC clone, if that is your preferred backup method.

**Note:** It is not a wise idea to have a backup partition, (CCC, TM or otherwise,) on the same drive you're backing up. If the HD itself goes poof, you've lost the backups you need to restore your system.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this HD too. But I think you misunderstood me, I want to use the technique I described in the question to always have an instant bootable system (nightly updated) and additionally - on the same external HD but on a second partition - a backup with all changes since last night. Is this possible and if yes, how?